# extract the unique items

Tags: excel

```
Col A,Col B,Col C
Test1,Test1,Test3
Test2,Test1,Test3
```

Is there a way to go thru all cells and pick out the unique values and place them in a new column or something?

Comment: Using what (eyeballs & mouse, macros, a program)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045767/extracting-unique-values-from-a-list or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2007 at least, then you can just use Remove Duplicates function from Data tab.

Otherwise I think a little bit of VBA fairy dust sprinkling is in order. I can mash up a quick VBA script if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers on [Getting unique values in Excel by using formulas only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only) only work for values in a single column.

For a solution that works for values in multiple rows and columns, I found the following formula very useful, from http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/16/unique-values-from-multiple-columns-using-array-formulas/
Oscar at get-digital.help.com even goes through it step-by-step and with a visualized example.

1) Give the range of values the label tbl_text

2) Apply the following array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, to cell B13 in this case. Change $B$12:B12 to refer to the cell above the cell you enter this formula into.

```
    =INDEX(tbl_text, MIN(IF(COUNTIF($B$12:B12, tbl_text)=0, ROW(tbl_text)-MIN(ROW(tbl_text))+1)), MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$12:B12, INDEX(tbl_text, MIN(IF(COUNTIF($B$12:B12, tbl_text)=0, ROW(tbl_text)-MIN(ROW(tbl_text))+1)), , 1)), 0), 1)
```

3) Copy/drag down until you get N/A's.